# How do blur points when it is not selected by a filter in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to implement a filter to be able to blur all points on my map.

```
 const nzgdFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
          url: "url...",
          definitionExpression:"",
        });

        nzgdFeatureLayer
          .when(() => {
            view.whenLayerView(nzgdFeatureLayer).then((layerView) => {});
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        nzgdFeatureLayer.featureEffect = new FeatureEffect({
          filter: new FeatureFilter({
            where: " 1=1 ",
          }),
          excludedEffect: "blur(3px) ",
        });
        webmap.layers.push(nzgdFeatureLayer);
```

I tried the above method but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your where clause is "1=1", and you are using an **excludeEffect**. This means, everything that *does not match* the where clause will get the effect. You can either change it to an **includeEffect**, or change the where clause to something like "1=2".